# Setting the button onclick and listener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have a numpad created using buttons in a gridlayout and I need to edit a EditText field. Here's my code now :

MainActivity.java:

```
    Button b1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
```

main.xml:

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:text="1"
        android:background="#ff3aaebb"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

The thing is I need to be able to get the text in the EditText and modify it and I don't know if it's easier to create one listener and do a case or do android:onClick="mymethod". If you can explain the differences/perks I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a method in XML layout generally is a bad idea - hard to track, not very intuitive if someone else except you tries to work on your app/part.

For multitude of buttons which share same click functionally you can assign your activity as a click listener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // your logic for the edit text
        ...
        editText.setText("ADD YOUR CHANGED VALUE");
    }
}
```

If you need to separate click logic foe different buttons, then you need to compare one by one

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (b1.equals(view)) {
        // b1 was clicked
        ...
        editText.setText(b1.getText());
    }
    else if (b2.equals(view)) {
        // b2 was clicked
        ...
        editText.setText(b2.getText());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting class or interface expected on extends and such !

Comment: Answer updated. For your activity, just append `implements View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Thanks ! But what is ApplicationActivity ? It says that it should be declared in a file named in ApplicationActivity.java.

Comment: Answer code changed since you are using `MainActivity`

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is still one part that was not answered, what about the EditText ?

Comment: Answer updated there too. Not very clear what are you expecting for the edit text. I presume changing its value.

Comment: Essentially, I need to get the current text in the EditText and change it's value using the numpad. Basically using it as a keyboard.